# Connecting actions to buttons in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

How do I connect a button added in Interface Builder to an action? This is what my instructions for adding a forum component in to my app. It says "Connect the action of that button to your "launchSatisfactionRemoteComponent:" method in IB." This would need to happen in my "Support.xib" window. Where is the code where you connect the action to that?

Comment: There's no code. In your xib file, select the receiver object from the  left pane (you need a receiver object), right-click/ctrl+click it, and drag the dot next to the name of the method you want to call to the button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your code, add the method to handle that action. For instance,

.h file

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSLog(@"Button Tapped!");
}
```

Now, open you xib file, right click to File's Owner, there you should see your method, drag the plus circle onto your button. You should see a bunch of different actions, most of the time **touchUpInside** is what you are looking for.